# How can I securely conceal the Azure blob URL used by front-end code for fetching data?

Tags: reactjs, azure

I created a front end app which uses azure storage blob url for the data.
Anyone can inspect element and get the url of that data.

What can I do? to hide the link or restrict peoples access to the data directly with the link.

My front end is hosted in cloudflare.

I tried setting up the CORS only allowing my public site but then data is not shared at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [shared access signature (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) with "Read" permissions in the backend and send this to the frontend (if possible only for authenticated users). This token can then be used to read the files from the blob storage for a certain amount of time (until expiry).

Comment: I'm using the SAS token to GET the data by fetch.
Thing is I cannot create a backend server.
My app will only be front end.

Also I cannot create CORS settings in Azure.

As this is a client side app so the api request will be on client site too.

Comment: You will need some type of authentication or at least a backend server otherwise this is simply not possible.